# Strange typedef for std::ptrdiff_t and std::size_t

Tags: c++

The type `std::size_t` is an unsigned type that can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type, and `std::ptrdiff_t` is a signed type that can hold the difference of two pointers (which is another way of saying that it should be the standard integer for array indexing in C++). The C++ standard library has decided to use `std::size_t` for array indexing but it is often stated that `std::ptrdiff_t` is a better choice. Which one is the best is a long debate which I don't want to enter here, but I have always thought that the second is the unsigned version of the first. Running this program on macOS give

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>

void f(int n) { std::printf("int"); };
void f(long n) { std::printf("long"); };
void f(long long n) { std::printf("long long"); };
void f(unsigned int n) { std::printf("unsigned int"); };
void f(unsigned long n) { std::printf("unsigned long"); };
void f(unsigned long long n) { std::printf("unsigned long long"); };

int main() {
  const std::ptrdiff_t n_ptrdiff = 0;
  const std::size_t n_size = 0;

  std::printf("std::ptrdiff_t is an alias for ");
  f(n_ptrdiff);
  std::printf("\n");

  std::printf("std::size_t is an alias for ");
  f(n_size);
  std::printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

On a 64-bit platform but compiled for 32-bit:

```
clang++ -m32 -std=c++11 type.cpp -o type-32-clang
```

gives me the following result:

```
std::ptrdiff_t is an alias for int
std::size_t is an alias for unsigned long
```

In this case `std::size_t` is not the unsigned version of `std::ptrdiff_t` even though they have the same storage size (4 bytes). Although it is in conformance with the standard, it seems very weird to me.

Does anyone knows of a rationale for this choice?

Comment: _"The type `std::size_t` is an unsigned type that is big enough to hold any pointer"_ Huh? What please?

Comment: ... That would be the optional [`std::uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: On a 32-bit platform, a `long` can have the same size of an `int`. Check the `sizeof` of all those types.

Comment: @Bob: It turns out that on this platform `int` and `long` have the same size (32 bits). But they are still different types. It shows when using overloading.

Comment: So you are going to incorporate material from answers into your own question, and invalidate them?

Comment: Look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t where it shows `typedef /*implementation-defined*/ ptrdiff_t;`. Now your snippet could be: https://ideone.com/rJlmVp

Comment: @StoryTeller: I have changed my question so that people cannot point out the errors in my question and forget to answer the question. But I am not the one who invalidated them.

Comment: No, it is you. The error was fundamental to answering the question, since you clearly exhibited a misunderstanding. Now that you rolled that into your question, to save face, all that's left is not that good of a question.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That was not my intent. My question was not formulated in a right way and I have used the comments to make it better. As it is now, the question is the one I have always wanted to ask. Maybe that's not the question you wanted to answer, and I am sorry for that. Concerning invalidation of answers, I did not do anything as I have no idea on how these things work on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Off: another good reason not to use function-overload, at least for so inadequately defined types like int/long/long long/ptrdff_t/etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: For compatibility with other systems, which did this for compatibility with yet other systems, which etc.

---

clang would normally have had `signed long` and `unsigned long` for `ptrdiff_t` and `size_t` as you expected, but [commit "fix some differences between apple gcc and clang on darwin/x86-32"](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/d427ad4cceab4481be0ac5cc2a190148ccc181e2) changed `ptrdiff_t` to `signed int` for compatibility with gcc. You can't have clang and gcc use the same C++ libraries if they disagree on basic typedefs such as these.

gcc uses `unsigned long` for `size_t` but `signed int` for `ptrdiff_t` because that's what Apple contributed: [commit "Add Darwin (Mac OS X kernel) native support."](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/80d725d710017efdde55743bdfb2163ce3a1ecf2) shows in `gcc/config/darwin.h`:

> ```
> /* Target definitions for Darwin (Mac OS X) systems.
>    Copyright (C) 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 2000, 2001
>    Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>    Contributed by Apple Computer Inc.
>
> [...]
>
> /* The string value for __SIZE_TYPE__.  */
>
> #ifndef SIZE_TYPE
> #define SIZE_TYPE "long unsigned int"
> #endif
>
> /* Type used for ptrdiff_t, as a string used in a declaration.  */
>
> #undef  PTRDIFF_TYPE
> #define PTRDIFF_TYPE "int"
> ```

No specific reason is mentioned, but this file is not specific to any processor type, it applies to all Darwin systems, and the commit also touches `gcc/config/rs6000/rs6000.h`, making it likely that it was for compatibility with *that*, bringing it back to 1995 for [commit "Add preliminary V.4 and eABI support."](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/3bfee51a5bd88bf54bc2e279046815d48df81509):

> ```
> /* Type used for ptrdiff_t, as a string used in a declaration.  */
> #undef  PTRDIFF_TYPE
> #define PTRDIFF_TYPE "int"
> ```

Since this doesn't redefine `SIZE_TYPE`, that's left at the default value of `"unsigned long"`.

gcc was not the system compiler for this platform, so *that* in turn was likely for compatibility with IBM's compiler. Which seems to be supported by [`gcc/config/rs6000/aix43.h`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/8cda90b94c780e6692186bb077c09e9900e5cf8a):

> ```
> /* AIX 4.3 typedefs ptrdiff_t as "long" while earlier releases used "int".  */
>
> #undef PTRDIFF_TYPE
> #define PTRDIFF_TYPE "long int"
> ```

Going back further than that probably isn't going to happen, since the history for AIX is not public.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer.